# jQuery id selectors stuck while fading between <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, quote, fading

I'm a jQuery/javascript newbie and I'm having an issue with jQuery which got me stuck for the past few days.
It's a script that switches from 3 different divs. It does switch from the first one to the second, but it freezes the script if the random selection tries to switch from the second to the third.

**html**

```
<span class="block">
    <span class="text1 _shown">1111</span>
    <span class="text2 _hidden">2222</span>
    <span class="text3 _hidden">3333</span>
</span>
<span class="block">
    <span class="text1 _shown">1111</span>
    <span class="text2 _hidden">2222</span>
    <span class="text3 _hidden">3333</span>
</span>
```

**css**

```
.block{
position:relative;
display:inline-block;
}

._shown{    
position:relative;
    display:block;
}
._hidden{
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
jQuery(function() {
var nbcases = $(".block").length;
var nbvignomg = $(".imgcases").length;
var i;

var chkcases = new Array();
for(var j = 0; j < nbcases-nbvignomg; j++){
chkcases.push(1);
}

function showNextTranscri() {
    i = Math.floor(Math.random()*(nbcases-nbvignomg));

    $('#texteTransis').html(chkcases);
    $('#texteTransis2').html(i);

    if(chkcases[i] == 1){
        $('.text1').eq(i).fadeOut(700, function() {
            $('.text1').eq(i).removeClass("_shown").addClass("_hidden");
            $('.text2').eq(i).removeClass("_hidden").addClass("_shown");
            chkcases[i] = 2;
            $('.text2').eq(i).hide().fadeIn(700).delay(500, showNextTranscri);
            });
    }
    if(chkcases[i] == 2){
        $('#texteTransis3').html('[x]');
        $('.text2').eq(i).fadeOut(700, function() {
            $('.text2').eq(i).removeClass("_shown").addClass("_hidden");
            $('.text3').eq(i).removeClass("_hidden").addClass("_shown");
            $('.text3').eq(i).fadeIn(700).delay(500, showNextTranscri);
            chkcases[i] = 3 ;
            });
    }
    if(chkcases[i] == 3){
        $('.text3').eq(i).fadeOut(700, function() {
            $('.text3').eq(i).removeClass("_shown").addClass("_hidden");
            $('.text1').eq(i).removeClass("_hidden").addClass("_shown");
            $('.text1').eq(i).fadeIn(700).delay(500, showNextTranscri);
            chkcases[i] = 1;
            });
    }
}

showNextTranscri();

})();
```

It seems to be my jQuery line that won't proceed and stucks the entire thing

```
 $('.caseh1#transcri2').eq(i).fadeOut(700, function() {
 $('.caseh1#transcri3').eq(i).fadeIn(700).delay(500, showNextQuote);
```

Thank you very much for any help you can provide.

**EDIT**: updated with clearer code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<del>**HTML**</del>

```
<div id="block1" class="block">
    <span class="text1 _shown">one</span>
    <span class="text2 _hidden">two</span>
</div>
<div id="block2" class="block">
    <span class="text1 _shown">three</span>
    <span class="text2 _hidden">four</span>
</div>
<div id="block3" class="block">
    <span class="text1 _hidden">five</span>
    <span class="text2 _shown">six</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
._shown
{
    display:block;
}
._hidden
{
    display: none;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
jQuery(function(){
    var block_array = jQuery(".block");
    var used_blocks = [];

    var getBlock = function(){
        var random_block = "block"+(Math.floor(Math.random()*block_array.length)+1);
        var used = false;
        for(key in used_blocks){
            if(random_block===used_blocks[key])
                used = true;
        };
        if(!used)
            return random_block;
        else
            return getBlock();
    };
    var setBlock = function(bid){
        if(used_blocks.length===block_array.length-1)
            used_blocks=[];
        else
            used_blocks.push(bid);
    };

    var showNextQuote = function(){

        var blockId = getBlock();
        setBlock(blockId);

        var shown = jQuery("#"+blockId+" ._shown");
        var hidden = jQuery("#"+blockId+" ._hidden");
        shown.fadeOut(700, function(){
            hidden.fadeIn(700,function(){
                shown.removeClass("_shown").addClass("_hidden");
                hidden.removeClass("_hidden").addClass("_shown");
                setTimeout(showNextQuote(),500);
            });
        });
    };
    showNextQuote();
});
```

**EDIT**

Modified code to fit your explanations in this answer's comments; should be everything you need.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5hQAj/2/)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I didn't know you couldn't use multiple id's. But in my case, your code doesn't seem to work the way I need it : My html does have multiple divs such as :
`<div>
<span id="transcri1" class="caseh1">one_2</span>
<span id="transcri2" class="caseh1">two_2</span>
<span id="transcri3" class="caseh1">three_2</span>
</div>`
You can check the URL above. Each text block has it's own id="transcrix" x3 (which is bad, ok) generated by php.

I'd like jQuery to randomly select a block, switch to the next <span>, and loop to another random block.

Comment: @NelsonS What do you mean by *switch to the next <span>, and loop to another random block*?

Comment: Made it work, I shoudl always test first :| [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wFze2/).

Comment: Thanks Philippe. I think it works now, but I don't think i'll be able to make it work for the 3 different <span> in each block: [jsfiddle (such as the html here)](http://jsfiddle.net/D7WC2/2/)

Comment: Thanks so much, it works great. Now I need a few more days to understand what you wrote! Thanks again for your time.